# Shell script to write user defined string into a file

Tags: shell, sh

I was wondering if there is any method in Linux to read a string from the user, store it in a variable and then insert the variable(entire string) into a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do it but I typically do something like this:

```
read usr_in
echo $usr_in > usr_input
```

`read` stores whatever is typed next in the variable `usr_in`. `echo` then prints/redirects the value of `usr_in` to the text file `usr_input`

Use `>>` instead of `>` if you want to append to rather than overwrite the file. Use `echo -n` if you don't want to add a newline after the string entered by the user (e.g. if the user is entering a password, entering something that's passed to a hashing algorithm or similarly "pedantic" stuff).

Answer (score 1):

Create shell script with:

```
vi usershell.sh
```

Enter the script to gather user defined string:

```
read user_data
echo $user_data >> user_string
```

Execute the shell script

It will ask user to enter string and will store it in file called “user_string”.